# Converting a complex vector to a sparse diagonal array in Julia

Tags: matlab, julia, sparse-matrix, diagonal

Trying to replicate a calculation from Matlab in Julia but am having trouble converting a single column complex array into a sparse diagonalized array for matrix multiplication.

Here is the Matlab code I am trying to replicate in Julia:

```
x*diag(sparse(y))
```

where `x` is of size `60,600000` and is of type: double, and `y` is size `600000,1` and is of type: complex double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Diagonal` for that:

```
using LinearAlgebra
x=rand(6,60)
y=rand(Complex{Float64},60,1)
x*Diagonal(view(y,:))
```

I have used `view(y,:)` to convert `y` to a `Vector` - this is here a dimension drop operator you can also use shorter form `vec(y)` instead. Depending on what you want to do you might explicitly say that you want first column by `view(y,:,1)`.

Note that `Diagonal` is just a sparse representation of a matrix.

```
julia> Diagonal(1:4)
4×4 Diagonal{Int64,UnitRange{Int64}}:
 1  ⋅  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  2  ⋅  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  3  ⋅
 ⋅  ⋅  ⋅  4
```

Another option that might cover more use case scenarios are `BandedMatrices`:

```
using BandedMatrices
x*BandedMatrix(0=>view(y,:))
```

Note that `BandedMatrix` uses set of pairs for bands, where band 0 is actually the diagonal.

Comment: In this particular case, `x .* y'` should result in the same, right?. It would be interesting to benchmark what is better. (And congrats on 10k!)

Comment: You can write `Diagonal(vec(y))` instead of `Diagonal(view(y, :))`. `vec` is also non-allocating, but you end up with a nicer type signature, and it's easier to write. `vec` is a really nice function.

Comment: @phipsgabler  Thank you!   `x .* y'` seem to return a different result.

Comment: @DNF yeah I should type `vec(y)` since it is shorter but somehow every time I automatically forget it ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't mean it like this, but one can also interpret the question in the way that `y` is a sparse vector in the Julia sense, and you want to construct a sparse diagonal matrix out of it.  In that case you can do the following:

```
julia> y = sprand(10, 0.2)
10-element SparseVector{Float64,Int64} with 2 stored entries:
  [4 ]  =  0.389682
  [5 ]  =  0.232429

julia> I, V = findnz(y)
([4, 5], [0.3896822408908356, 0.2324294021548845])

julia> sparse(I, I, V)
5×5 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64} with 2 stored entries:
  [4, 4]  =  0.389682
  [5, 5]  =  0.232429
```

Unfortunately, `spdiagm` does not preserve structural zeros for a sparse input:

```
julia> spdiagm(0 => y)
10×10 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64,Int64} with 10 stored entries:
  [1 ,  1]  =  0.0
  [2 ,  2]  =  0.0
  [3 ,  3]  =  0.0
  [4 ,  4]  =  0.389682
  [5 ,  5]  =  0.232429
  [6 ,  6]  =  0.0
  [7 ,  7]  =  0.0
  [8 ,  8]  =  0.0
  [9 ,  9]  =  0.0
  [10, 10]  =  0.0
```

I don't know whether this is intentional, but I filed [an issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/37174) about this behaviour.

Comment: Note that `Diagonal` or `BandedMatrix` can have more efficient memory storage (because they explicitly know the data structure and support only this data structure). Hence while `SparseArrays` is far more flexible this also must come with significant performance cost.